# Split a Rectangle into n equal Parts

Tags: c#, geometry, diagram, rectangles

I need to split a rectangle Rect Structure, Rect(Double X, Double Y, Double Width, Double Height) into a number of smaller rectangles/structures for n = 2, n= 4 and n = 6, i define a Rect for my Diagram (Nodes and Links) that bounds the whole Diagram

```
Rect b = activeDiagram.Panel.DiagramBounds;
```

Can someone provide an example of doing it with my structure in C#?

Comment: Can you perhaps provide an example or more information on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: hi im using PDFSharp for creating PDF-Document for some diagrams. after converting my diagrams in PDF, i should print them on one Page for very small Diagrams, but if i have big-Diagrams then printing them on one Page produce a bad Printing quality the diagram will be small displayed and the diagram content is not readable. becuase of that i want to split splint diagrams in 2 Parts or 4 Parts depending on there Size

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question completely, but is it as simple as slicing it up in one direction?

```
Rect[] smallerRects = new Rect[n];
for(int i = 0;i < n;++i)
   smallerRects[i] = new Rect(b.X + b.Width / n * i, b.Y, b.Width / n, b.Height);
```